# Example Price Model Numbers for Google App Engine hosted game?

Tags: facebook-apps, google-app-engine

I'm working at a startup developing a Facebook app using Google App Engine for the hosting. Right now we're still in development and so using GAE under the free quota. The current rates (as of the time of this question) are as follows:

- CPU Time: $0.10/CPU hour
- Bandwidth Out: $0.12/GB
- Bandwidth In: $0.10/GB
- Stored Data: $0.005/GB-day
- Recipients Emailed: $0.0001/Email

In order to plan where the pricing will fall we're trying to come up with base estimates for these values which we don't yet have. The app is a Facebook game, does anyone have some sample numbers we can plug in based on other games running on Facebook/GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.appdata.com/ is a good source of statistics for facebook applications.

I am a facebook app developer myself, and I can say that any estimates you put out are going to be unrealistic. Just make sure you have good analytics so you can predict growth after you establish yourself, and don't rely on any proprietary GAE features in case you suddenly find yourself needing to switch hosting.

Comment: Perfect, exactly the kind of stats I was looking for.